# Jetpack Compose access and interact with semantics tree from application

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to build a feature in my application where I want to be able to fill some text fields inside a composable and maybe click some buttons just like it is possible in tests:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
    MyAppTheme {
        MainScreen(uiState = fakeUiState, /*...*/)
    }
}

composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Continue").performClick()
```

The question is how is this possible to do in the application, because as far as I know the semantics tree is available for debug apps and frameworks for automation testing have the possibility of accessing it.